# SwiftmailerBundle how can send email with html content? Symfony 2

Tags: html, email, symfony

i try to send template with html content
but in email i received only text

how can i set for send email with html content?

```
$messaggio = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject('Hello Email')
                ->setFrom('mittente@example.com')
                ->setTo('ffff@hotmail.it')
                ->setBody($this->renderView('AcmeUserBundle:Default:email.text.twig'))
                ;
                $this->get('mailer')->send($messaggio);
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Specify content-type using `->setContentType("text/html")`

Answer (score 13):

You have to specify 'text/html' type:

```
->setBody($this->renderView('...:....html.twig'), 'text/html')
```